# How to count how many number of value 1 in spesific row

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have matrix :

```
 A=[ 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0;
     0 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 0;
     1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

I want to search for the number `1` in my matrix from rows `4` to `6`. I want to know the number only if the column elements at the same index prior to it are smaller than `3`.

For example:

At row `4` the number `1` is at the 3rd position, but there exists a value `3` in row `1` at the same position in a previous row. Thus this should be neglected and proceed to find the next.

At row `6`, the condition fails, and it should be returned.

Comment: what about looping through and using an if statement. Im not to familiar with matlab but that is what I would do in other languages.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you just want to count the elements that are equal to one in a specific row?

Comment: I don't understand the second part of your question. You want to find how many times `1` appears in rows `4-6`. It is `3` times. What next?

Comment: i want to count the element that has value "1" in 4th-6th row and have same column position with element that has value "<3".

Comment: Look at the comment on my answer by @aka.nice...Do you want to check for `>3` only the columns from `1` *up to* `6` (and not `7` and onwards?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
C = sum( A(4:6,all(A(1:6,:)<3,1)) == 1, 2)
```

The part `B = A(4:6,all(A(1:6,:)<3,1))` extracts rows 4 through 6 and applies the `<3` limit on all columns, from row 1 to 6. Then, equating `B == 1` and summing over the rows will result in

```
C = [0
     0
     1];
```

Comment: But how would this expression restrict to rows prior to it? If there is a value >= 3 in the same column but in a posterior row, the 1 will be skipped, try to apply to [0;0;0; 1; 0; 3]

Comment: @aka.nice Not sure what you mean...wasn't that the intention?

Comment: @aka.nice Yes, it would seem I've just misread the question. This edit should fix that.